# Can't ignore specific file for Git push Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, github, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

So I am trying to push changes to Github for an existing project in Visual Studio 2022. When I first attempted, I got the following error:
[image: GitHub push error]

I originally had no .gitignore file, I added it after the changes were made. I attempted to add the [Redacted]/obj/Release folder to a newly created gitIgnore file, commited changes, then attemped push. Same error.

**Also, that Zip file in the above picture doesnt exist initially, I cant navigate to it in File Explorer unless its hidden in a spot I dont know about. It must be generated during the push. **

Then I attempted to use git commands to refresh the cache:

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

Still won't work after this. Below is what I added to my .gitignore file:[image]

The blacked-out text is just the name of the solution. I also tried without the parentheses after obj/Release and obj/Debug.

Let me know if any more information is required and I will add it. Thank you.

Comment: Was this zip file ever committed to the Git repo?

Comment: You need to remove the large file from *every* commit reachable by your branch. This means you'll need to rewrite the history of your branch. If you have a commit that deletes the file, try interactive rebase and squashing the delete commit into the commit that added the file.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti It looks like that is true, yes. I see it in github now from a previous commit.

Comment: @TTT Thank you, that makes sense, I will look up how to do an interactive rebase and report back once Ive done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file in question was committed at one point in the repository, it needs to be removed in order to push the local copy to GitHub.

There are many tools that let you do this, such as [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) or `git filter-branch`.

I personally like to use [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

Once you have it installed, you can remove the single file causing the issue:

```bash
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-match /path/to/your/file.zip
```

You can also proactively remove anything that will cause an error:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M
```

**WARNING**

This operation is a destructive operation meaning it will rewrite your commit history and Git SHAs will change as the result. Make sure you are doing this on a fresh clone and you have a backup of the repository in the event you need to revert the changes.

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to comment to let you know that worked. I appreciate it.